# How can I print out push notifications when app is in foreground or background?

Tags: ios, swift

I recently got push notifications to work, however now I'm stuck with determining how to push certain views depending on what push notification is sent to the user.

In the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function, the println statement does not print when I receive a push notification despite appearing while the app is in the background.

I would like to print out each remote push notification that the phone receives so I can then determine how to set up the logic to handle it?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println("Recived: \(userInfo)")


}
```

Comment: Can you at least add here your relevant code? maybe from your AppDelegate?

Comment: @Asaf I added the code I currently have!

Comment: You need to add additional logic. Adding a key/value pair to your remote notification payload, getting that value in the delegate method. Then you can act accordingly, i.e. Present a particular view controller or view etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this delegate method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    println("Recived: \(userInfo)")
}
```

As mentioned at the Apple docs:

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app. Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

For more info [check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:).